# C# to VB.NET Events

Tags: c#, vb.net, events

I'm having problems translating this into VB:

```
public delegate void ChangeMessageEvent(string message);
public static event ChangeMessageEvent ChangeMessage = null;
```

Also this doesn't seem to work

```
if (oStatusManager.ChangeMessage != null)
        {
          oStatusManager.ChangeMessage(message);
          Application.DoEvents();

}
```

Error MSG:

> 'Public Shared Shadows Event ChangeMessage(message As String)' is an
>   event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to
>   raise an event.

VB Code:

I used developer fusion to convert it

Here nothing is underlined and says: End of statement expected

```
Public Delegate Sub ChangeMessageEvent(message As String)
Public Shared Event ChangeMessage As ChangeMessageEvent = Nothing

If oStatusManager.ChangeMessage IsNot Nothing Then
    oStatusManager.ChangeMessage(message)
    Application.DoEvents()
End If
```

for the above line

> 'Public Shared Event ChangeMessage(message As String)' is an event,
>   and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise
>   an event.

Comment: Exactly as the error message states. It's an event not a method.

Comment: This works perfectly in C# how can I get it to work in VB?

Comment: Show us your VB code. Might be able to tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172877.aspx

Comment: Every time someone uses `Application.DoEvents`, I cry a little, die a little.

Comment: @MarcGravell: I wish there was a variation of `DoEvents` which would allow only those events which would be valid with a modal dialog box open, since that's what's really needed 99% of the time code does `DoEvents`.

Comment: Have you looked up the `RaiseEvent` statement?

Comment: Main problem is that I can't define and event of a delegate type         Public Delegate Sub ChangeMessageEvent(ByVal message As String)
Public Shared Event ChangeMessage As ChangeMessageEvent

Answer (score 1):

Two things - drop the " = Nothing" and use the hidden VB 'Event' field - or drop the conditional altogether since VB does the check within the 'RaiseEvent':

```
Public Delegate Sub ChangeMessageEvent(ByVal message As String)
Public Shared Event ChangeMessage As ChangeMessageEvent

Private Sub test()
    If oStatusManager.ChangeMessageEvent IsNot Nothing Then
        RaiseEvent oStatusManager.ChangeMessage(message)
        Application.DoEvents()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply mate, I still get "delegate Class 'ChangeMessageEvent' conflicts with a member implicitly declared for event 'ChangeMessage' in class 'oStatusManager'.

Comment: Remove the conditional altogether then - i.e., you don't need the "If oStatusManager..." condition at all.

Comment: I tried that, still get the same error on the definition: Public Shared Event ChangeMessage As ChangeMessageEvent

Comment: Change the name of the "ChangeMessage" event or change the name of the  "ChangeMessageEvent" delegate - the VB hidden field "ChangeMessageEvent" is conflicting with the delegate's name.

Comment: The problem is that VB uses a hidden field named the same as the event with "Event" added to it, so if you name anything <event>Event, you'll get a conflict.  The VB error messages aren't very good at making this clear.